# Obter o valor por uma comparação entre Arrays C#

Tags: c#

Bem, tenho dois arrays:

**1º**

```
string[] pastasSistema = new string[]
         {
                "Content",
                "DataRv",
                "My Skype Received Files",
                "RootTools",
                "shared_dynco",
                "shared_httpfe"
         };
```

**2º**

```
string[] diretorios= new string[]
     {
            "Content",
            "DataRv",
            "My Skype Received Files",
            "Diferente",
            "RootTools",
            "shared_dynco",
            "shared_httpfe"
     };
```

Onde tenho a pasta `Diferente`. O que quero fazer, é comparar esses dois arrays, e obter o conteúdo que for diferente. No caso estou querendo ter o valor **DIFERENTE** de dentro do `Array diretorios`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [**`Except`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) do Linq, assim

```
string[] diff = diretorios.Except(pastasSistema).ToArray();
```

Perceba que o **`Except`** só pega os itens do primeiro array que não estejam no segundo, exatamente como você pede

> No caso estou querendo ter o valor DIFERENTE de dentro do Array diretorios

Answer (score 2):

Um método mais trivial seria percorrer ambos arrays:

```
List<string> diferentes = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < diretorios.Length; j++) {
    bool existe = false

    for (int j = 0; j < pastasSistema.Length && !existe; j++) {
        if(diretorios[i].Equals(pastaSistema[j])) existe = true
    }
    if(!existe) diferentes.Add(diretorios[i]);

}
```

Mas a linguagem contém metodos mais simples que fazem isso para você. Olhe a resposta do jbueno